# PatchValue on a nested FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have this form that has a nested form array that holds date values. When the user selects a date, a function is called that formats the date and should update the form's value.
But, I am having a hard time understanding how to get access to the specific formcontrol in the array...
This is the relevant code

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private datepipe: DatePipe) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

      loading: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });

 }

  get loadingForm(){

    return this.form.get('loading') as FormArray
  }

  addLoadingTimes(){

    const loading = this.formBuilder.group({

      StartLoadDate: [],
      EndLoadDate: []

    })

    this.loadingForm.push(loading);
  }


  //format date from datepicker 

  changeDateTimeEvent(event:MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>, index, controlName) {


    const d = new Date(event.value);
    const date = this.datepipe.transform(d, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss');


    this.form.controls['loading'][controlName].at(index).patchValue(date);

  }
```

Right now, I am trying to update the value with this line:

```
 this.form.controls['loading'][controlName].at(index).patchValue(date);
```

but, apparently, is wrong...
Could anybody help?

Here is a blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-patchvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FormArray method has **[at](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at)** method to access specific control use that to setValue.

**Try this:**

```
changeDateTimeEvent(event:MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>, index, controlName) {
     const d = new Date(event.value);
     const day = this.datepipe.transform(d, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss');
     let formName : string;
     this.loadingForm.at(index).get(controlName).setValue(day);

}
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-patchvalue-yoyxfg)

Comment: A minute ago, I was able to solve it like this:

`let loadingGroup = this.loadingForm.controls[index] as FormGroup ;`
`loadingGroup.controls[controlName].patchValue(day);`

but this is much sleeker.. Thanks you!!!